# Reactjs Module CSS multiple class selector

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I'm trying to implement or add multiple class in out container when I click a button. But it seems that the styling is not being applied. Below are my code

> Layout.module.css

```
.Content {
    padding-left: 240px;
    min-height: calc(100vh);
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 80px;
    background: #eee;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    transition: padding-left 0.2s linear;
}

.Content.collapse {
    padding-left: 100px;
    display: block;
    transition: padding-left 0.2s linear ;
}
```

Now I added the collapse class in my nav component like so

```
const layout = (props) => (
    <Aux>        
        <Sidebar collapse={props.collapse} />        
        <div className={`${classes.Content} ${props.collapse ? 'collapse' : ''}`}>
            <TopNavigation toggle={props.toggle}/>
            {props.children}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    </Aux>  
);
```

So basically I'm just checking the props if it's collapse or not. If it is then I'll add a text `collapse` in the class.
Now when I click on a button it sets the state.collapse = true/false.  It was able to do it's job. Now it seems that it's not reading my css style. Below is the generated class in my DOM

[image]

Notice the class `.Content` styling was detected. But as you can see here

`Layout_Content__2WLOk collapse` the div container has a class of collapse. So I was thinking it should read the `.Content.collapse` selector. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try `${props.collapse ? classes.collapse : ''}` instead of `${props.collapse ? 'collapse' : ''}`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli dude you should put this as your answer. This solves my problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using CSS modules, it creates a unique classname for each class for each instance of the component.

So you need to use the imported classes to have access to the generated classnames, just like you do for the `.Content`

So

```
<div className={`${classes.Content} ${props.collapse ? classes.collapse : ''}`}>
```

Answer (score 1):

## You are using a string not the generated hash

this part will not work

```
${props.collapse ? 'collapse' : ''}
```

### Quick fix

Try not chaining it.

```
.collapse {
    padding-left: 100px;
    display: block;
    transition: padding-left 0.2s linear ;
}
```

and add

`classes.collapse` instead of `collapse`

```
${props.collapse ? classes.collapse : ''}
```

Comment: Nice answer. This actually solves it just like @Gabriele answer

Answer (score -1):

In React you need to use the keyword 'className' instead of 'class'

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname

Also if you want to use CSS Modules you need to import your Layout.module.css file like this

```
import styles from './Layout.module.css';
```

And you can add CSS selector like this

```
<div className={styles.Content}></div>
```

you can study this here https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Comment: Yeah I just modified it with className but the same thing